# Mutual inductive coupling and proximity effects

Tags: mutual-inductance, proximity

I am struggling a bit to differentiate between proximity effect and mutual inductive coupling. Proximity effect: if a conductor is carrying an alternative current the nearby conductors will witness an increase in their resistance (proximity effect resistance) because of the modification in their current distribution. Whereas the mutual inductive coupling generates an induced emf. Isn't the impact the same, making thus proximity effect = mutual inductive coupling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the proximity effect causes current crowding in the conductors.  The effect of this is to increase the AC resistance of the conductors.  You can see the effect in Dowell's curves for AC resistance (normalized) vs. number of layers of conductors wound on a bobbin or core: (From [here](https://www.eetimes.com/power-tip-26-current-distribution-in-high-frequency-conductors/#).)

[image]

Mutual inductive coupling may influence the current distribution in adjacent conductors, but its main effect is inducing an EMF in the conductor. You can have different amounts of inductive coupling and independently different amounts of proximity effect induced AC resistance increase depending on geometry.  So they are not the same effect.

Comment: Understood. Thank you!